# Unable to see datalabels on chartjs in LWC

Tags: chart.js, salesforce, lwc

Trying to display datalabels on the a pie chart using chartjs library in LWC. Tried both version pairs for chartjs and chartjs datalabel plugins libraries (V4.2.1- chartjs & V2.2.0 - chartjs-datalabel-plugin) & (v2.8-chartjs & v1.0-chartjs-datalabel-plugin) as mentioned in few other posts. But unable to get the datalabels displayed. Below is my code. Must be missing something basic.

testChart.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</template>
```

testChart.js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjs';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import ChartDataLabels from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chartjsdatalabels';

export default class TestChart extends LightningElement {
    chartJsInitialized = false;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.chartJsInitialized) {
            return;
        }
        this.chartJsInitialized = true;

        Promise.all([
          loadScript(this, chartjs),loadScript(this, ChartDataLabels)
        ]).then(() => {
          console.log('ChartJS and ChartJS Datalabels scripts loaded successfully.');
            this.initializeChart();
            
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    initializeChart() {
        const data = {
            labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [30, 50, 20],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        };
        const options = {
          responsive: false,
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              anchor: 'end',
              align: 'end',
              labels: {
                value: {
                  color: 'blue'
                }
              }
    
            }
          }
        };
        //chartjs.Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
        const chart = new window.Chart(this.template.querySelector('canvas'), {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            options: options
        });
    }
}
```

Please help in finding the solution

Comment: This may not answer your question directly, but when working with 3rd party libraries like chartjs in LWC, it may be helpful to enable the light dom feature. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_light_dom

You may encounter some unexpected results when rendering content like chartjs within the shadow dom.

Comment: For what it's worth, your code works fine in standard vanilla js [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fucp68ka/) - it only needed a `padding` to show the "50" label. Still, when testing with issues it's better to use `anchor: 'middle',` to make sure labels are not cropped out, which is a possibility with labels positioned outside of the pie.